# Naive bayes text classification laplace smoothing

Tags: classification, bayesian, smoothing

I am trying to implement naive bayes classifier and really confused problem of laplace smoothing.

The probability of get word in class C is:

```
<pre>  
    P(Wi|C) = (count(Wi,C) + 1) / (count(all, C) + |V|)  
</pre>
```

But what is V? Is it vocabulary of only training corpus? Or V is whole english vocabulary?

Answer (score 0):

It should be the vocabulary of the training corpus.

Answer (score 0):

Laplace smoothing in Naive Bayes is used to maintain Bias- variance trade off or over fitting - under fitting problem.

It adds hyper parameter (Alpha) to your numerator and denominator field to your formula. You have to tune this parameter for choosing better model using GridSearch or RandomSearch techniques. https://towardsdatascience.com/hyperparameter-tuning-c5619e7e6624